# Yii: Following strict MVC rules to ensure that all the business logic is in appropriate places

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

Sticking to MVC basics in Yii, I am trying to embed my business rules in the model class but facing problem in implementing it. The problem at hand is to stop the user from making duplicate entries and code the function in model class that checks if the entry already exists in table. I want to write a method in my model class which would query the sames model's underlying table and if the new business entity exists, it simply returns false. If I code this in controller, I can achieve the desired functionality but I want to keep this in model so that where ever the model is used, I can access the method and also stick to MVC basics which dictates Thin Controllers and Thick Models. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cross-site Request Forgery Prevention](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security#cross-site-request-forgery-prevention) may be what you are looking for? unless your idea of 'duplicate entries' is directly related to your business model, in which case you can override the [CActiveRecord.beforeSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#beforeSave-detail) and put your logic in there, if this method returns false, the record won't be saved to the database.

If you use the later method, and you want to pass the error to the view and display to the user, you can always use the [CModel.addError()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel/#addError-detail) method, in this case in your beforeSave method.

There is another option though, which is using [custom validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule).

which is more appropriate? depends on your business logic.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working the way I wanted. However one thing, I want to get the error text that I wrote in beforeSave modle's method so that I could show it to end user. I did this: $error=$modelVar->save(); but was unable to get my error text, instead the error is logged in the Yii log file. I am doing an ajax call and need to return the error text to the user the way I am raising it in the beforeSave method. any clues? Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to avoid the use of active record instances (at least) directly in the controller.

Instead you should create [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29)-like structures, which contains the interaction between your `CActiveRecord` and `CFormModel` instances. This would let you better isolate the presentation layer (views, controllers and templates) from model layer.

Such services also would be able to hold (and sometimes, react upon) errors/exceptions thrown by `CActiveRecord` and `CFormModel` instances, that it utilizes.